# which is more appropriate - swamped with some work or swamped with work

Tags: word-usage, american-english

I want to express that there was a lot of work and so I couldn't look into some other things 
I found the word "swamp" represents this idea well. I could think of using it in two different ways:

1. I got swamped with some work  <-- I am not sure if this is correct or conveys the meaning.
   Or probably it conveys I got swamped with some work other than the task at hand so that I couldn't look into it.
2. I got swamped with work

Comment: Because ***some** work* implies ***not all***, it also usually implies ***not a large quantity** of work*. Hence it doesn't work at all well in the context of someone being ***swamped*** (which implies there ***is*** a large quantity of something that's doing the swamping).

Comment: If you had a brief period where you had a lot of things all due at the same time, you might say "I was busy with some work". "Swamped" denotes something more serious and overwhelming than just having a lot to do one afternoon: if it's a more serious and longer term problem, then do as FumbleFingers says, "swamped with work".

Answer (score 1):

Generally the second usage is more appropriate in natural context.

"Overwhelmed with work" might be better if you talking to non native speakers.

The first usage is wordy and might confuse someone.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to express that there was a lot of work and so I couldn't look
> into some other things

You may use such expressions as

*I'm up to my ears in work*

*I'm buried in work**

*I'm overloaded with work*

*I'm stretched/spread thin* (at work).

As for the use of "swamped",  you may be *swamped with new customers*.

Also, you may be *snowed under with (numerous) complaints.*